# Error whilst trying to install fbprophet on mac

Tags: python-3.x, pip, facebook-prophet

I am seeing following error whilst trying to install fbprophet on mac. I tried even using conda to install but failing at pystan step.

```
      TypeError: This is a python-holidays entity loader class. For entity inheritance purposes please import a class you want to derive from directly: e.g., `from holidays.countries import Entity` or `from holidays.financial import Entity`.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fbprophet
  Running setup.py clean for fbprophet
Failed to build fbprophet
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fbprophet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0):

Try install pystan like this and then install prophet. While installing pystan it's possible to get some errors

```
pip install pystan==2.19.1.1
pip install prophet
```